# Howto block (social media) websites on lumia?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I want to avoid wasting time on social media websites. I block them on my windows pc by adding them to the "hosts" file. I can still access the sites via wifi from my mobile (lumia). So I also block them in my router. That only works for http but not https url's.

Is there a way to block selected sites on the phone browser, or the phone itself? Maybe there is an app for that?

Comment: No chance, sorry to disappoint you. There is no way to block websites on the phone itself and because of the sandbox system, no app could ever do that.

Comment: edit: I solved it by configuring my router to connect to an opendns account I created, that blocks the sites I want.